# Using Cygwin to test in Linux

Tags: windows, linux

I have downloaded cygwin on my windows xp system. how do i launch Internet Explorer and a website I have created?? I want to test my website to see if it works with Linux. Is this the right way to go about it?

Comment: You test a web site with a browser, not with an operating system.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test your web application on Linux (which would mean using browsers on Linux), it would be better if you used a VM with Linux installed in it rather than use Cygwin. The latter adds a layer of complexity which you have to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it's Linux won't matter at all if it works on browsers that work on Linux. For example, Firefox has a Linux version and if it works on your Windows Firefox, it'll work fine in Firefox always, no matter what operating system the user has.

To do this, if you don't have a Linux machine set up, I'd use a site like: http://browsershots.org/ to test many browsers all at once.

Comment: I tried to run VM but it says that "FATAL: Could not read from the boot medium! System Halted". What do i need to solve this??

Comment: Are you using VirtualBox to run the VM?

Comment: Doing a little Googling, assuming you're running VirtualBox, this seems to be a very common error. I've got a little experience using VirtualBox myself, but don't remember running into this problem. It probably has something to do with the ISO of Linux you're trying to run/mount, but could be a number of issues. Look at these; see if they help your specific problem. http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=10780, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=642480, http://bit.ly/ms2smU

Answer (score 0):

At first you should get a good introduction on website development, then you should try http://browsershots.org , as JTroland suggested. Internet Explorer is not the only browser on the world.